# Connecting to wireless printer with cable to router

Tags: wireless-networking, network-printer

The little network that I am dealing with consists of my laptop with Windows 10, a VirtualBox Ubuntu virutal machine, a wireless printer, and a router/WAP.

The VirtualBox network settings are set to bridged, but although I have internet connectivity for both the VM and the host, they are not on the same subnet. (I plan to fix this sometime soon.) But what I don't understand is the relationship between my host and my printer vs. my VM and my printer. When my host is connected to my router with a patch cable (which I prefer to have it), it cannot connect to the printer to send print jobs. If I pull out the ethernet cable, it is immediately connected to the printer once they are on the same wireless network. However, my VM is connected to the printer even while the ethernet cable is connected to my laptop.

I don't really understand how everything in my network is connecting here, but I would really like to be able to connect to the printer while connecting to the router through the ethernet cable. The fact that my VM seems capable of that makes me think that might be possible, but I don't know what I would need to do.

(How) can I connect to the printer while on the wired connection to the router?

(If more info would be useful please let me know.)

Comment: Try to set the network settings of the VM to "Network Address Translation (NAT)", so both VM and host are on the same network segment.

Comment: @harrymc I imagine that will cause the VM to not be able to connect, rather than causing the host to be able to connect. While the VM is off, the host cannot connect while wired.

Comment: This will cause the VM to be exactly equal to the host. So what works for one will work for the other. Windows should then use the wired connection and disable the wireless,

Comment: @harrymc My issue isn't that I want them to work the same. I want the wired connection to be able to connect to the wireless printer, which currently it cannot. Making the VM equal to the host will give the VM the issue that I have with the host, which would not solve my problem. I don't actually care (right now) how the VM works. I was only using the VM to demonstrate that somehow it seems that what I want to do with the host is possible.

Comment: Windows 10 is very bad about using two network adapters in parallel. This is probably your problem.